# finding largest consecutive region in table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm trying to find regions in a file that have consecutive lines based on two columns. I want to find the largest span of consecutive values. If column 4 (V3) comes immediately before the second line's value for column 3 (V2), then write the output for the longest span of consecutive values.

The input looks like this. input:

```
> x
   grp   V1   V2  V3  V4  V5 V6 
1:   1 DOG.1 142 144 132 134  0  
2:   2 DOG.1 313 315 303 305  0  
3:   3 DOG.1 316 318 306 308  0  
4:   4 DOG.1 319 321 309 311  0 
5:   5 DOG.1 322 324 312 314  0
```

the output should look like this:

```
      out.name  in  out  
[1,] "DOG.1" "313" "324"
```

Notice how the x[1,] was removed and how the output is starting at x[2,3] and ending at x[5,4]. All of these values are consecutive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious way is to take `tail(x$V2, -1L) - head(x$V3, -1L)` and get the start and end indices corresponding to the maximum consecutive `1`s. But I'll skip it here (and leave it to others) as I'd like to show how this can be done with the help of [`IRanges` package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html):

```
require(data.table)
require(IRanges) ## Bioconductor package

x.ir = reduce(IRanges(x$V2, x$V3))
max.idx = which.max(width(x.ir))

ans = data.table(out.name = "DOG.1", 
                 in = start(x.ir)[max.idx], 
                 out = end(x.ir)[max.idx])

#    out.name bla out
# 1:    DOG.1 313 324
```